# Git push without pull

Tags: java, git, github, push, pull

I'm making a school project with my class mates, and one of them has broke the main of the program and he push it to github. I have the project without the main modified and it works perfectly. Is there any way so I can push my files without making the pull, and replace the bad ones with mine?

Answer (score 5):

If the other dev has pushed relevant changes, you should not just wipe them out, but merge in both of your changes.

The best solution, provided the dev has push other meaningful changes, is to just resolve the conflicts, and fix the broken code.

From your diverged commits, move them to a new branch, then merge back into master - resolving conflicts when you do.

```
# Create a new branch with your commits
git checkout -b featureBranch

# Get master from origin
git checkout master
git pull origin master

# Add in your changes
git merge featureBranch

# Resolve Conflicts

# Push to origin
git push origin master
```

---

If you truly want to just erase his commits ( **which I do not suggest you do** ), you can just force your push - this will overwrite everything on the server with what you have on your machine.

Every other dev who is working on the project will need to take additional actions on there end, as you are now changing history; this is not advised.

```
git push origin master --force
```

---

There is also a [`revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) method; this will create a new commit that completely reverses the changes of a chosen commit; to use this, you first need a clean working tree.

```
# Move your commits to a new branch
git checkout -b featureBranch

# Get latest changes from master
git checkout master
git pull origin master

# Create new commit that reverses the other devs changes
git revert hashToRevert

# Pull in your additional commits
git merge featureBranch

# Push to master
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `git revert` command to revert that commit. This will do a new commit that undoes all the changes made by that previous commit, documentation [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes#git-revert):

> The git revert command undoes a committed snapshot. But, instead of
>   removing the commit from the project history, it figures out how to
>   undo the changes introduced by the commit and appends a new commit
>   with the resulting content.

Once done, you can push youw own changes on top of reverted commit.